# Abstract class Implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, abstract-class

I have an abstract class as seen below. I have 2 concrete classes for this abstract class. My problem is that 1 of the concrete classes needs to implement a method that is not required by class2. So I wouldn't want to call that method in the abstract class as not all concretions depend on it. But the calling code will call the execute() method in the abstract class. It is the entry point to the program. My quesion is how would I refactor this

```
Abstract class A{

    abstract void doOne();
    abstract void doTwo();

    public void execute(){
        //.... Lots of common code used by both Class1 and Class2
        doOne();
        //....
        doTwo()
        //...
        //Method should only be implemented by Class 1 and not by Class 2
        CallOnlyClass1()
    }

}

Class class1 extends A{

}

Class class2 extends A{
```

Comment: In class 1, override the method, and call the `super` version in it. Then do the stuff only it should do.

Comment: `class2` can still have the method, but with an empty body. This is often referred to as [a template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) (although that usually has much more meat).

Comment: Okay thanks. I was trying to avoid that but I guess thats the best option here

Comment: @Mguy Did you forget this question? :P

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to avoid leaking concretion details in the abstraction and therefore make the design less ackward is to to make the extension point less specific.

For exemple, if you name the method `postExecute` then you allow `Class2` to call it's own method in that extension point. If `postExecute` doesn't always need to be implemented then you could have a default empty implementation in the abstract class.

Without knowing more about the concrete model and problem I can't really propose alternative designs, but you could also attempt to explore using composition rather than inheritance and template methods.